# Counter.most_common is a little misleading

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
min_number_of_tops = 3
c = Counter(['x','b','c','d','e','x','b','c','d','x','b'])
print(c.most_common(min_number_of_tops))
```

outputs either:

```
[('b', 3), ('x', 3), ('c', 2)]
```

or:

```
[('b', 3), ('x', 3), ('d', 2)]
```

but I'd preferred if `most_common` had returned something like this instead:

```
[('b', 3), ('x', 3), ('d', 2), ('c', 2)]
```

as I am interested in including all elements with a given count.

Anyway, I need to produce a sorted list representing the top results, but to also return any other items that had the same count of the 3rd item. For example:

```
['x', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Here is my attempt at producing this list:

```
def elements_above_cutoff(elem_value_pairs, cutoff):
    ''' presuming that the pairs are sorted from highest value to lowest '''
    for e,v in elem_value_pairs:
        if v >= cutoff:
            yield e
        else:
            return

min_number_of_tops = 3
c = Counter(['x','b','c','d','e','x','b','c','d','x','b'])
print(list(elements_above_cutoff(c.most_common(),c.most_common(min_number_of_tops)[-1][1])))
```

Which gives:

```
['b', 'x', 'd', 'c']
```

Can you suggest a nicer way of doing this? I'm using python3.

Answer (score 0):

This simple approach works:

```
import collections
common = collections.Counter(['x','b','c','d','e','x','b','c','d','x','b']).most_common()
min_number_of_tops = 3
if len(common)>min_number_of_tops:
    freq = common[min_number_of_tops-1][1]
    for i in range(min_number_of_tops, len(common)):
        if common[i][1] < freq:
            common = common[:i]
            break
print(common)
```

Output:

```
[('b', 3), ('x', 3), ('d', 2), ('c', 2)]
```

A slightly more refined way using a list comprehension, might be less readable though:

```
import collections
common = collections.Counter(['x','b','c','d','e','x','b','c','d','x','b']).most_common()
min_number_of_tops = 3
testfreq = common[min_number_of_tops-1][1] if len(common)>min_number_of_tops else 0
common = [x for x, freq in common if freq >= testfreq]
print(common)
```

Output:

```
['b', 'x', 'd', 'c']
```

Comment: Yes that is correct! I'll add your wording to my question.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think there is. Only your call to the function makes it a bit difficult to understand the logic behind the algorithm.

For example this code is less elegant, but I hope is more easy to understand; as it is posted not to propose a solution, but just to allow others to better understand the nature of your question.

```
from collections import Counter
from typing import Generator

def most_common_elements_above_cutoff(counter:Counter, cutoff:int) -> Generator[str, None, None]:

   elem_value_pairs = counter.most_common()
   partial_count = 0
   temporary_max_occurrences = elem_value_pairs[0][1]

   for (element,occurrences) in elem_value_pairs:
     if partial_count < cutoff:
       if occurrences != temporary_max_occurrences:
         temporary_max_occurrences = occurrences
       partial_count += 1
     else:
       if occurrences != temporary_max_occurrences:
         break
     yield element

min_number_of_tops = 3
c = Counter(['x','b','c','d','e','x','b','c','d','x','b'])

print(list(most_common_elements_above_cutoff(c, min_number_of_tops)))
```